# Using tab-indentation in a space-indentation project

Tags: git, editor, sublimetext2, indentation

I have been experimenting lately with proportional fonts and tab-indentation. The problem is that some of the projects I work on are indented with spaces (2 for Ruby, 4 for JavaScript).

What I want to do is **read and edit** the files with tab-indentation but actually **share them with my team members** with space-indentation. We use **git** for source control and I use **Sublime Text 2** as an editor.

**Has anyone tried this yet?**

Would it be better to let the editor control the indentation or should I make git handle it?

Comment: Sublime Text 2 which is weapon of choice for Ruby, has translate tab to spaces property, so you set your IDE handle that. I do not see a good reason for you to force tab spacing, do you have one?

Comment: I want to use tabs for indentation because spaces do not play well with proportional fonts.

Comment: ok then, git is your solution and here is how you do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs, hope it is worth it :)

Comment: Great one! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was to use **git** for this just like it documented on [Can git automatically switch between spaces and tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2316677/146272)